Get ItemsControl Items collection as collection of visual elements
I'm developing a graphics library.
The principle is quite simple, all chart types inherit from a BaseChart class, which inherits from ItemsControl. This BaseChart offers a Render() method and requires a list of ChartElements.
A ChartContainer contains and manages many charts. Whenever a chart or chart element is changed, the ChartContainer is notified and calls the Render() methods of all its children.
As you can see below, it works pretty well.
<tools:ChartContainer>
    <tools:BarChart Color="DarkOrange" ItemsSource="{Binding DataSet1}" FillOpacity="0.2" StrokeThickness="2"/>
    <tools:LineChart Color="Purple" ItemsSource="{Binding DataSet2}" StrokeThickness="4"/>
    <tools:LineChart Color="Cyan" ItemsSource="{Binding DataSet3}" StrokeThickness="4" StrokeDashArray="3"/>
</tools:ChartContainer>

(https://i.sstatic.net/OlpIbxD1.png)
But, it works only if I bind a ChartElement collection.

1st problem : It forces the user to create an ChartElement ObservableCollection in his ViewModel.
2nd problem : To display my ChartElements, I edit their size and their Canvas position. So I can not use the same datas on multiple charts.

Here is the BaseChart code and an exemple of chart:
public abstract class BaseChart : ItemsControl
{
    public static readonly RoutedEvent DataChangedEvent;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorProperty;

    public SolidColorBrush Color
    {
        get => (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(ColorProperty);
        set => SetValue(ColorProperty, value);
    }

    public event RoutedEventHandler DatasChanged
    {
        add => AddHandler(DataChangedEvent, value);
        remove => RemoveHandler(DataChangedEvent, value);
    }

    static BaseChart()
    {
        ColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Color", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(BaseChart));
        DataChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("DatasChanged", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(BaseChart));
    }

    public BaseChart()
    {
        Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("HorizontalValue", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        drawArea = GetTemplateChild("PART_Draw") as Canvas;
        if (drawArea != null)
        {
            //UpdateDrawingArea();
            RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(DataChangedEvent));
            drawArea.SizeChanged += (sender, e) => Render();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnItemsSourceChanged(IEnumerable oldValue, IEnumerable newValue)
    {
        //Reset Canvas elements
        RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(DataChangedEvent));

        //Remove CollectionChanged handler
        var oldDatas = (ObservableCollection<ChartElement>)oldValue;
        if (oldDatas != null)
            oldDatas.CollectionChanged -= OnDatasCollectionChanged;

        //Add CollectionChanged handler
        var newDatas = (ObservableCollection<ChartElement>)newValue;
        if (newDatas != null)
        {
            newDatas.CollectionChanged += OnDatasCollectionChanged;
            foreach (ChartElement element in newDatas)
            {
                //Get notified when an element is changed
                element.ValuesChanged -= OnValueChanged;
                element.ValuesChanged += OnValueChanged;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnDatasCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Unsubscribe to romoved items
        if (e.OldItems != null)
            foreach (ChartElement element in e.OldItems)
                element.ValuesChanged -= OnValueChanged;

        //Subscribe to new items
        if (e.NewItems != null)
            foreach (ChartElement element in e.NewItems)
                element.ValuesChanged += OnValueChanged;
    }

    private void OnValueChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(DataChangedEvent));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Render the chart, each chart must override this method
    /// </summary>
    public abstract void Render();

    public double GetVerticalPosition(double value)
    {
        double range = MaxVertical - MinVertical;
        double ratioValue = 1.0 / range * (value - MinVertical);
        return drawArea.ActualHeight - drawArea.ActualHeight * ratioValue;
    }

    public double GetHorizontalPosition(double value)
    {
        double range = MaxHorizontal - MinHorizontal;
        double ratioValue = 1.0 / range * (value - MinHorizontal);
        return drawArea.ActualWidth * ratioValue;
    }
}

public class ScatterChart : BaseChart
{
    static ScatterChart()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ScatterChart), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ScatterChart)));
    }

    public override void Render()
    {
        if (drawArea != null && Items != null && Items.Count > 0)
        {
            //Clear all
            UpdateDrawingArea();

            foreach (ChartElement element in Items)
            {
                element.Width = double.NaN;
                element.Height = double.NaN;
                Canvas.SetTop(element, GetVerticalPosition(element.VerticalValue));
                Canvas.SetLeft(element, GetHorizontalPosition(element.HorizontalValue));
            }
        }
    }
}

A better approch would be biding a collection of ViewModels and defining an ItemTemplate:
<tools:ChartContainer>
    <tools:BarChart Color="DarkOrange" ItemsSource="{Binding myViewModelCollection}">
        <tools:BarChart.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <tools:ChartElement HorizontalValue="{Binding myViewModelProp1}" VerticalValue="{Binding myViewModelProp2}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </tools:BarChart.ItemTemplate>
    </tools:BarChart>
</tools:ChartContainer>

But this XAML does not works because in this case my Items property contains a collection of ViewModels and I can not convert them into ChartElements.
I know there is something to do with the ItemContainerGenerator, but I can't find what. The ItemContainerGenerator status stays to "NotStarted" and I don't really know how to use it.
I tried to add those methods but without any success:
protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
{
    return item is ChartElement;
}

protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
{
    return new ChartElement();
}

Also when I call ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as ChartElement, is always return null.

Overriding GetContainerForItemOverride and related methods is the correct approach. There should however not be another ChartElement in the ItemTemplate. There would instead be an ItemContainerStyle (with TargetType="tools:ChartElement") that declares the Bindings to the view model item.

First problem is that you make your control to depend on the data items. Your control should only treat or know data models as of type object.This is the reason you have to force the client to use a certain data type which severely limits the usability of your control. Instead you must arrange item containers e.g. ContentControl. Let the user provide a data converter that extracts the necessary information e.g. x-y coordinates, from the anonymous data model. This will also solve problem 2) and Allies you to display the same model data in different plots.

The ItemContainerGenrrator is used by the panel that generates and hosts the item containers. You didn't have to get about it in order to render the items. The Canvas will do all this. GetContainerForItemOverride() is called in this context to provide the appropriate other container to the panel. You can add code to GetContainerForItemOverride() that positions the containers on the Canvas
